# Permission denied on new users even after chmod a+x on parent dir

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

The alias I'd like to allow the users to use is:

```
alias arkin='(cd /mnt/Storage/Path/to/Dir/ && ./scriptToRun.sh)'
```

But other than my user (owner), I get -bash: cd: /mnt/Storage/Path/to/Dir/: Permission Denied

```
$ls -l
drwxrwxrwx 6 me mygroup 4096 Mar 11 11:20 DirInQuestion
```

Comment: Do `sudo arkin`

Comment: what about `chmod -R 755 /mnt/Storage/Path/to/Dir/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a file or directory on Linux, in addition to having permissions on that file or directory, you need execute permission on all parent directories, which would in your case be `/mnt`, `/mnt/Storage`, and so on. Your users are likely missing one of these permissions.

Comment: @Matt Koerber, Joseph is right: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory#answer-13891

Comment: Thanks for the help guys... I thought I had the permissions right but only had it back to Storage.